# Calculating distance and angle between two points, C# program

Tags: c#, mathematics

I like to think I'm an intermediate programmer, but I learned to code with the Unity engine so I'm still getting used to not using it, and I've never had someone review my code before. I don't know any other programmers, most people in my town don't even have a computer. I'd appreciate it greatly if you'd be so kind and tell me what you think of my little script here. Rather, be brutal if you want.

My script works fine, but I have some concerns, like the readability of calling a Boolean method with a bunch of parameters in the condition of a while loop for example.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Course_Assignment
{
class DistanceCalculator
{
    /// <summary>
    /// This class calculates the distance between two points and the angle of the slope.
    /// </summary>

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        float point1X = 0;
        float point1Y = 0;
        float point2X = 0;
        float point2Y = 0;

        float deltaX = 0;
        float deltaY = 0;

        double distance = 0;
        double angle;

        Console.WriteLine("Welcome. This program calculates the distance \nbetween two points as well as their angle.\nPlease type the prompted values.");

        //GetPoints() defines all the point coordinates via user input and 
        //returns true if the data entered was invalid.  
        NewPoints : while (GetPoints(ref point1X, ref point1Y, ref point2X, ref point2Y))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Invalid data has been entered. Try again.");
        }

        //Getting the change in x and y from point 1 to 2.
        deltaX = point2X - point1X;
        deltaY = point2Y - point1Y;

        //Calc() uses the Pythagorean Theorem to calculate and return       
        //distance, and calculates angle in degrees by multiplying the
        //tangent of deltaX and deltaY.
        distance = Calc(deltaX, deltaY, out angle);

        //Displaying calculations
        Console.WriteLine("\nDistance: {0:N3}\nAngle: {1:N3} degrees\nWould you like to calculate new points? (y,n)", distance, angle);

        //User decides whether or not to do new calculations.
        string newCalc = Console.ReadLine().ToLower();

        if (newCalc.Equals("y") || newCalc.Equals("yes"))
        {
            goto NewPoints;
        }
        else return;
    }

    static bool GetPoints(ref float newPoint1X, ref float newPoint1Y, ref float newPoint2X, ref float newPoint2Y)
    {

        bool invalid = false;

        //Prompts user for coordinates and sets the cursor in front of the 
        //prompt for neatness, then checks validity of user input 
        Console.WriteLine("\nPoint 1\nX Coordinate: ");
        Console.SetCursorPosition(14, Console.CursorTop - 1);
        if (!float.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out newPoint1X))
        {
            invalid =  true;
            return invalid;
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Y Coordinate: ");
        Console.SetCursorPosition(14, Console.CursorTop - 1);
        if (!float.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out newPoint1Y))
        {
            invalid = true;
            return invalid;
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Point 2\nX Coordinate: ");
        Console.SetCursorPosition(14, Console.CursorTop - 1);
        if (!float.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out newPoint2X))
        {
            invalid = true;
            return invalid;
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Y Coordinate: ");
        Console.SetCursorPosition(14, Console.CursorTop - 1);
        if (!float.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out newPoint2Y))
        {
            invalid = true;
            return invalid;
        }   

        return invalid;
    }

    static double Calc(float deltaX, float deltaY, out double angle)
    {
        double newDistance = Math.Sqrt((deltaX * deltaX) + (deltaY * deltaY));
        angle = (Math.Atan2(deltaY, deltaX)) * (180 / Math.PI);
        return newDistance;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: I'd recommend taking a look at the [System.Window.Point](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.point(v=vs.110).aspx) and [System.Windows.Vector](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.vector(v=vs.110).aspx) structures.

Comment: I would have concerns about user experience - if they got a single character wrong, all previous values are lost.

Comment: Oh wow, I was trying to implement vectors similar to those in Unity but I after some tinkering I thought they didn't exist. Those links are definitely helpful. 

wondra, excellent point, I should have made it reset the invalid coordinate instead of all of them. I think that's what I wanted to do at first, but the simplicity of going to the beginning of the script won me over and I forgot about user friendliness.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. You should avoid using `goto` statements. Not because it took me a minute to recall what `NewPoints :` syntax even means, but because `goto` makes it extremely hard to follow the execution flow. Cases where `goto` makes code more readable are rare, and yours is not on of those. Just use another `while` (or `do while`) loop instead.
2. `Calc` is a poor name for a method, because it doesn't say anything about what sort of calculation it performs. It calculates distance you say? Name it `CalcDistance` then. Oh, wait, it also calculates angle! Maybe `CalcDistanceAndAngle` then? That doesn't look right... Which is an indication, that you probably need two separate methods: one to calculate angle and one to calculate distance (related to [SRP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle)).

   ```
   var distance = CalcDistance(...);
   var angle = CalcAngle(...);
   ```
3. There is a lot of copy-pasting in `GetPoints` method. You should probably have a method to query single value. For example

   ```
   static float RequestValue(string message)
   { 
       float value;
       while (true) 
       {
           Console.WriteLine(message);
           Console.SetCursorPosition(14, Console.CursorTop - 1);
           if (float.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out value)) break;
           Console.WriteLine("Invalid data has been entered. Try again."); 
       } 
       return value;
   }
   ```

   Then you can just initialize individual points:

   ```
   var point1X = RequestValue("\nPoint 1\nX Coordinate: ");
   ```
4. I am pretty sure you don't need to move cursor, if you call `Console.Write` instead of `Console.WriteLine`.
5. You are using both floats and doubles in your calculations. You should probably use one or the other.
6. `else return;` is unnecessary.
7. I think it would make more sense for `Calc` to take actual points as input instead of "delta"-s. Meaning you should move:

   > ```
   > //Getting the change in x and y from point 1 to 2.
   > deltaX = point2X - point1X;
   > deltaY = point2Y - point1Y;
   > ```

   inside `Calc`'s body.

Comment: Excellent advice, thank you. I'm especially grateful for that SRP link. I encountered that a long time ago but I don't think I really understood it enough at the time for it to make a real impression, and the links on that wiki will help too.

Answer (score 4):

> ```
> string newCalc = Console.ReadLine().ToLower();
> ..
> if (newCalc.Equals("y") || newCalc.Equals("yes"))
> ```

If you are comparing strings like these you don't shouldn't `ToLower` or `ToUpper` anything because it's not easy to find that you actually do a case insensitive comparison. I find it's cleaner if you use the case insensitive overload:

```
var newCalc = Console.ReadLine();
var yes =
   newCalc.Equals("y", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) ||
   newCalc.Equals("yes", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);

if (yes)
```

or even shorter with regex:

```
var yes = Regex.IsMatch(newCalc, "^(y|yes)$", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```